# Skype texting on iPhone no longer makes any sounds at all

Tags: iphone, ios, skype

No idea what's going on here, but sometime within the last week or so Skype on my iPhone SE has stopped making any text-related sounds.  Phone calls are fine including ringing and speaking/listening, but notifications will not make a sound.  iOS notifications for Skype are enabled, Notifications within Skype itself are enabled, and I am in "online" mode (not Do Not Disturb).  I have rebooted my phone, quit & relaunched Skype, etc.  Still no joy.

iPhone SE on iOS 10.3.1 (not willing to update to iOS11 so please don't even suggest it)
Skype 8.3.0.51670 (and no way am I updating Skype.  I made that mistake recently on another device and it was a disaster, plus it was working fine until very recently).

**EDIT:  And just like that, 20 minutes later... Skype started making noise again.  I have absolutely NO idea why... I didn't do a thing.**

**EDIT 2:  For whatever it's worth, Skype stopped making sounds again a couple days later.  Then started again.  It seems to basically just be random... sometimes it will make sounds, sometimes it won't.  No rhyme or reason!**

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you are in do not disturb mode as it affects it. Look for the moon symbol in the notification area.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no, definitely was not in DnD mode.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you have an older version of Skype on an older version of iOS.

While I understand why you would refrain from updating Skype or iOS, do keep in mind that they have likely fixed this issue with the updated version, hence why they update.

If this issue is a serious one for you, then I recommend the inevitable.

Comment: I disagree, because I have been running these versions of OS and Skype for a very long time and this was never an issue until recently.

Comment: Right and I understand that, but I'm just letting you know that if you were to contact Skype they will let you know right away that they no longer support older versions of software. And of course Apple would say the same. Its the gamble we take when we dont update our software. Even if things get worse, at least they are entitled to help you out with the issue vs not being updated.

Comment: Yes of course they would.  That's always Apple's excuse.  They push out an update and do everything they can to force you to use it - giving you absolutely no option to change your mind once installed (in the case of iOS).  I find that sort of behavior to be abhorrent and I refuse to "upgrade" to things I don't want just because they want me to.  I've had enough of Apple's updates destroying my work environments.  I appreciate where you're coming from, but I'm 100% certain my versions of software is not the issue here.